# Structure referenced through an array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, implicit-conversion

I am trying to set up an array of pointers that point to a structure.  I have tried two (2) methods and both give me compile errors.  Code examples below.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

In the first example I get a compile warning with

```
struct stPlanets *pPlanets = &planets;
```

The warning is :

> warning: initialization of ‘struct stPlanets *’ from incompatible
> pointer type ‘struct stPlanets (*)[5]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
> struct stPlanets *pPlanets = &planets;

Example 01.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct stPlanets {
        char    *planet;
        char    *deity[10];
    };  

    struct stPlanets planets[] = { 
        {"Mercury", {"Messenger"}},
        {"Venus", {"Love, Beauty"}},
        {"Earth", {"Earthly things"}},
        {"Mars", {"War"}},
        {"Jupiter", {"Sky, Thunder, King of gods"}}
    };  

    struct stPlanets *pPlanets = &planets;

    int     i = 0;
    int     sPlanets = sizeof(planets) / sizeof(struct stPlanets);

    printf("There are %d planets.\n", sPlanets);

    for (i = 0; i < sPlanets; i++)
    {   
        printf("%-10s : %s.\n", planets[i].planet, planets[i].deity[0]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Example 02.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct stPlanets {
        char    *planet;
        char    *deity[10];
    };  

    struct stPlanets *planets[] = { 
        {"Mercury", {"Messenger"}},
        {"Venus", {"Love, Beauty"}},
        {"Earth", {"Earthly things"}},
        {"Mars", {"War"}},
        {"Jupiter", {"Sky, Thunder, King of gods"}}
    };  

    int     i = 0;
    int     sPlanets = sizeof(planets) / sizeof(struct stPlanets);

    printf("There are %d planets.\n", sPlanets);

    for (i = 0; i < sPlanets; i++)
    {   
        printf("%-10s : %s.\n", planets[i]->planet, planets[i]->deity[0]); //abbreviated to just print first instance.
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

In the second example I get the following :

```
planets-06a.c:11:9: warning: braces around scalar initializer
         {"Mercury", {"Messenger"}},
         ^
planets-06a.c:11:9: note: (near initialization for ‘planets[0]’)
planets-06a.c:11:10: warning: initialization of ‘struct stPlanets *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         {"Mercury", {"Messenger"}},
          ^~~~~~~~~
planets-06a.c:11:10: note: (near initialization for ‘planets[0]’)
planets-06a.c:11:9: warning: braces around scalar initializer
         {"Mercury", {"Messenger"}},
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first code snippet you have to write

```
struct stPlanets *pPlanets = planets;
```

instead of

```
struct stPlanets *pPlanets = &planets;
```

or you could write

```
struct stPlanets ( *pPlanets )[5] = &planets;
```

That is an array designator used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So in this declaration

```
struct stPlanets *pPlanets = planets;
```

the declared object and the initializer (after implicit conversion) have the same type `struct stPlanets *`.

While in this declaration

```
struct stPlanets *pPlanets = &planets;
```

the initializer has the type `struct stPlanets ( * )[5]`. So the compiler issues a message that the declared object and the initializer have incompatible types.

In the second code snippet this declaration

```
struct stPlanets *planets[] = { 
    {"Mercury", {"Messenger"}},
    {"Venus", {"Love, Beauty"}},
    {"Earth", {"Earthly things"}},
    {"Mars", {"War"}},
    {"Jupiter", {"Sky, Thunder, King of gods"}}
};
```

is incorrect because you need at first define objects of the structure that will be pointed to by elements of the array of pointers.

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct stPlanets {
        char    *planet;
        char    *deity[10];
    };  

    struct stPlanets planets[] = { 
        {"Mercury", {"Messenger"}},
        {"Venus", {"Love, Beauty"}},
        {"Earth", {"Earthly things"}},
        {"Mars", {"War"}},
        {"Jupiter", {"Sky, Thunder, King of gods"}}
    };  

    struct stPlanets *pPlanets = planets;

    size_t     sPlanets = sizeof(planets) / sizeof( *planets );

    printf("There are %zu planets.\n", sPlanets);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sPlanets; i++ )
    {   
        printf("%-10s : %s.\n", pPlanets[i].planet, pPlanets[i].deity[0]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Mercury    : Messenger.
Venus      : Love, Beauty.
Earth      : Earthly things.
Mars       : War.
Jupiter    : Sky, Thunder, King of gods.
```